# How to store multiple files name into phpmyadmin database using foreach?

Tags: php, html, foreach

The code below does not work. What is the solution for this problem OR any suggestion and what is the most correct way to solve this problem?

HTML Code

```
<form action="includes/galleryAddImagesCMS.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="container">
                    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                        <label>
                        <input type="hidden" name="albumName" value="<?php echo $albumName ?>"/>
                        <input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile[]" multiple/>

                        Choose File
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="image_preview"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name='submitImage' value="Upload Image"/>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The following below is PHP CODE

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submitImage'])){
            $albumName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['albumName']);
            $sqlAlbumname="INSERT INTO gallery (GalleryName, Creationdate) VALUES ('$albumName', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";

            if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlAlbumname)){

                foreach ($_FILES["uploadFile"]["name"] as $key => $imagesname) {

                    $sqlPhotoGallery="INSERT INTO photogallery (PhotoName, Creationdate, GalleryID) 
                    VALUES ('$imagesname', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), (SELECT last_insert_id() FROM gallery))";

                    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPhotoGallery)){
                        echo "success";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_fetch\_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind\_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an syntax error in your query

```
\\You can use else condition to print the error of query
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPhotoGallery)){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

in your current code if you have multiple files then it will store multiple records in database.

you can use **JSON** to store file in single row

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)